# Need partition by three field and ranking

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query which fetches result by partitioning counterid, status, source  as rank.

Using query as

```
select ch.* except (seqnum, seqnum_s),
           row_number() over (partition by counter_id, status,source, (seqnum_s - seqnum)
                              order by transaction_time
                             ) as ranking
    from (select ch.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by counter_id order,status by transaction_time) as seqnum,
                 row_number() over (partition by counter_id, status,source order by transaction_time) as seqnum_s
          from counter_history ch
         ) ch;
```

but I need a result as given below.

```
CounterID   status    transaction_time      source      Rank
121         new       Nov-09-2019 8:32:19   UNDEFINED   1
121         new       Nov-09-2019 8:32:20   UNDEFINED   2
121         CLAIMED   Nov-09-2019 8:32:21   WORKFLOW    1
121         new       Nov-09-2019 8:32:22   WORKFLOW    1
121         CLAIMED   Nov-09-2019 8:32:59   external    1
121         CLAIMED   Nov-09-2019 8:33:00   external    2
121         CLAIMED   Nov-09-2019 8:33:01   external    3
233         new       Nov-09-2019 8:33:32   external    1
233         new       Nov-09-2019 8:49:58   internal    1
233         RESOLVED  Nov-13-2019 6:51:11   internal    1
233         CLAIMED   Nov-11-2019 22:15:52  WORKFLOW    1
233         new       Nov-11-2019 22:15:54  external    1
233         CLAIMED   Nov-11-2019 22:15:55  external    1
156         new       Nov-11-2019 22:15:56  UNDEFINED   1
156         CLAIMED   Nov-11-2019 22:16:24  WORKFLOW    1
156         CLAIMED   Nov-11-2019 22:16:28  external    2
156         RESOLVE   Nov-11-2019 22:16:56  external    1
```

Kindly help out if there is any issue in the query. using #standardsql Thanks

Comment: There is little chance that one can answer without first seeing the sample data that corresponds to the expected results that you are showing, along with an explanation of what you are looking to do. Displaying the results that the query currently produces might also help.

Comment: @GMB 7, To be precise, I need to populate the rank coulmn based on three Field counterid status and source. In the order as the data is currently showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.counter_history` AS (
  SELECT 121 CounterID,         'new' status,       'Nov-09-2019 8:32:19' transaction_time,   'UNDEFINED' source UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'new',       'Nov-09-2019 8:32:20',   'UNDEFINED'   UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-09-2019 8:32:21',   'WORKFLOW'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'new',       'Nov-09-2019 8:32:22',   'WORKFLOW'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-09-2019 8:32:59',   'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-09-2019 8:33:00',   'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 121,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-09-2019 8:33:01',   'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'new',       'Nov-09-2019 8:33:32',   'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'new',       'Nov-09-2019 8:49:58',   'internal'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'RESOLVED',  'Nov-13-2019 6:51:11',   'internal'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-11-2019 22:15:52',  'WORKFLOW'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'new',       'Nov-11-2019 22:15:54',  'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 233,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-11-2019 22:15:55',  'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 156,         'new',       'Nov-11-2019 22:15:56',  'UNDEFINED'   UNION ALL
  SELECT 156,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-11-2019 22:16:24',  'WORKFLOW'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 156,         'CLAIMED',   'Nov-11-2019 22:16:28',  'external'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 156,         'RESOLVE',   'Nov-11-2019 22:16:56',  'external'  
), temp AS (
  SELECT * REPLACE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b-%d-%Y %T', transaction_time) AS transaction_time)
  FROM `project.dataset.counter_history`
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag, grp), 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CounterID, grp ORDER BY transaction_time) ranking 
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY CounterID ORDER BY transaction_time) grp 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, (status, source) != LAG((status, source)) OVER(PARTITION BY CounterID ORDER BY transaction_time) flag
    FROM temp
  )
)
-- ORDER BY CounterID, transaction_time
```

As you can see above also takes care of translating `transaction_time` presented as STRING data type to DATE, so ordering is done properly. without this output will be wrong!!

Comment: consider also voting up the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are starting over again for each counterid/source/status combination.  For that, tweak the query like this:

```
select ch.* except (seqnum, seqnum_s),
           row_number() over (partition by counter_id, status, source, (seqnum_s - seqnum)
                              order by transaction_time
                             ) as ranking
    from (select ch.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by counter_id order by transaction_time) as seqnum,
                 row_number() over (partition by counter_id, status, source order by transaction_time) as seqnum_s
          from counter_history ch
         ) ch;
```

The only difference from your query is that `status` and `source` are in the second `row_number()` and the first still counts only by `counter_id`.